# rasterFromXYZ projection is misaligned but drawing individual points lines up correctly

Tags: leaflet, r-raster, r-leaflet

I have lat/lon data with a value for each coordinate. I am trying to create a raster layer to use in leaflet where the values are mapped to a palette.

mydata has 3 cols, x, y, z (where z is value)

When I use `raster::rasterFromXYZ(mydata, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")` and then `leaflet() %>% addTiles %>% addRasterImage()` I get misaligned data:

[image]

However, when I just use `leaflet() %>% addTiles %>% Addcircles()` with the raw lat/lon/value data, it lines up correctly:

[image]

I know this isn't a reprex, but the data is massive and the misalignment isn't as obvious on a smaller scale.

Am I doing something wrong with the crs I've defined in `rasterFromXYZ`? Or is there some other issue?